# multiple function plots in one row using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to have two or more plots next to each other in a single row? I would like to use pgfplots to have some simple functions be plotted. Best thing would be to have a little arrow in between the plots as they shall represent changes in a sequence of functions. So basically I would like to have the following code be presented in one row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $h_0$
    ]
    \addplot[mark = none, thick]{1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\[\rightarrow\]

\begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $h_1$
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = none, thick, const plot, jump mark left]
        coordinates{
            (0,2) (0.5,-2) (1,-2)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add your complete code (with the `\documentclass` and the packages that you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

test, if this gives satisfactory result:

edit: to be top of diagrams in line you should ensure, that `yticklabel` is at both or none diagram at their tops. for example adding

```
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.1,
```

to the first diagrams gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16, width=0.4\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] % new, added option
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $h_0$
    ]
    \addplot[mark = none, thick]{1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad          % new
$\rightarrow$  % changed
\quad          % new
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] % new, added option
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $h_1$
    ]
    \addplot+[mark = none, thick, const plot, jump mark left]
        coordinates{
            (0,2) (0.5,-2) (1,-2)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost, I think the right plot is shifted upwards a bit.

EDIT: it's not, the labeling of the y-axis on the left graph makes it shift down a bit.

Comment: yes, it is. this  you can correct by defining `ymax` to plots or on other way which will move `yticklabel` on the first plot below top diagram border.